# Conda fails to build, when inside docker container

Tags: docker, anaconda, dockerfile, conda, conda-build

I am trying to build a docker image. This is the full dockerfile:

```
FROM ubuntu

ENV LANG=C.UTF-8 LC_ALL=C.UTF-8
ENV PATH /opt/conda/bin:$PATH

ENV TZ=Europe/Athens
RUN ln -snf /usr/share/zoneinfo/$TZ /etc/localtime && echo $TZ > /etc/timezone

RUN apt-get update --fix-missing && apt-get install -y wget bzip2 ca-certificates \
    libglib2.0-0 libxext6 libsm6 libxrender1 \
    git mercurial subversion

RUN wget --quiet https://repo.anaconda.com/miniconda/Miniconda2-4.5.11-Linux-x86_64.sh -O ~/miniconda.sh && \
    /bin/bash ~/miniconda.sh -b -p /opt/conda && \
    rm ~/miniconda.sh && \
    ln -s /opt/conda/etc/profile.d/conda.sh /etc/profile.d/conda.sh && \
    echo ". /opt/conda/etc/profile.d/conda.sh" >> ~/.bashrc && \
    echo "conda activate base" >> ~/.bashrc

RUN apt-get install -y curl grep sed dpkg && \
    TINI_VERSION=`curl https://github.com/krallin/tini/releases/latest | grep -o "/v.*\"" | sed 's:^..\(.*\).$:\1:'` && \
    curl -L "https://github.com/krallin/tini/releases/download/v${TINI_VERSION}/tini_${TINI_VERSION}.deb" > tini.deb && \
    dpkg -i tini.deb && \
    rm tini.deb && \
    apt-get clean

ENTRYPOINT [ "/usr/bin/tini", "--" ]
CMD [ "/bin/bash" ]

#SECOND PART
RUN apt install -y libgl1-mesa-glx
RUN conda install conda-build
RUN apt-get install -y git
WORKDIR /
RUN git clone https://github.com/cadquery/cadquery.git
WORKDIR /cadquery
RUN conda env create -n cq -f environment.yml
RUN echo "source activate cq" > ~/.bashrc
ENV PATH /opt/conda/envs/cq/bin:$PATH
WORKDIR /testing
```

However, when it is time to conda build - more specifically on STEP 12, this line here:

```
RUN conda install conda-build
```

i get errors.

It seems to be installing the packages normally, then it fails.:

```
Proceed ([y]/n)? 
ruamel_yaml-0.15.100 | 268 KB    | ########## | 100% 
readline-8.1         | 464 KB    | ########## | 100% 
bzip2-1.0.8          | 105 KB    | ########## | 100% 
tzdata-2020f         | 123 KB    | ########## | 100% 
xz-5.2.5             | 438 KB    | ########## | 100% 
tk-8.6.10            | 3.2 MB    | ########## | 100% 
conda-build-3.21.4   | 585 KB    | ########## | 100% 
cffi-1.14.5          | 227 KB    | ########## | 100% 
ld_impl_linux-64-2.3 | 645 KB    | ########## | 100% 
urllib3-1.26.4       | 99 KB     | ########## | 100% 
pyyaml-5.4.1         | 180 KB    | ########## | 100% 
pip-21.1.1           | 2.0 MB    | ########## | 100% 
lz4-c-1.9.3          | 216 KB    | ########## | 100% 
beautifulsoup4-4.9.3 | 86 KB     | ########## | 100% 
python-3.9.5         | 22.7 MB   | ########## | 100% 
pkginfo-1.7.0        | 42 KB     | ########## | 100% 
tqdm-4.59.0          | 90 KB     | ########## | 100% 
setuptools-52.0.0    | 880 KB    | ########## | 100% 
python-libarchive-c- | 50 KB     | ########## | 100% 
cryptography-3.4.7   | 1.0 MB    | ########## | 100% 
icu-58.2             | 22.7 MB   | ########## | 100% 
pysocks-1.7.1        | 31 KB     | ########## | 100% 
libxml2-2.9.10       | 1.3 MB    | ########## | 100% 
certifi-2020.12.5    | 143 KB    | ########## | 100% 
openssl-1.1.1k       | 3.8 MB    | ########## | 100% 
libgcc-ng-9.1.0      | 8.1 MB    | ########## | 100% 
patchelf-0.12        | 92 KB     | ########## | 100% 
glob2-0.7            | 12 KB     | ########## | 100% 
idna-2.10            | 52 KB     | ########## | 100% 
liblief-0.10.1       | 2.0 MB    | ########## | 100% 
pycparser-2.20       | 94 KB     | ########## | 100% 
chardet-4.0.0        | 198 KB    | ########## | 100% 
py-lief-0.10.1       | 1.3 MB    | ########## | 100% 
markupsafe-2.0.1     | 22 KB     | ########## | 100% 
zlib-1.2.11          | 120 KB    | ########## | 100% 
wheel-0.36.2         | 31 KB     | ########## | 100% 
conda-4.10.1         | 3.1 MB    | ########## | 100% 
libffi-3.3           | 54 KB     | ########## | 100% 
yaml-0.2.5           | 87 KB     | ########## | 100% 
libarchive-3.4.2     | 1.6 MB    | ########## | 100% 
ca-certificates-2021 | 120 KB    | ########## | 100% 
conda-package-handli | 967 KB    | ########## | 100% 
filelock-3.0.12      | 10 KB     | ########## | 100% 
requests-2.25.1      | 51 KB     | ########## | 100% 
ncurses-6.2          | 1.1 MB    | ########## | 100% 
pytz-2021.1          | 244 KB    | ########## | 100% 
pycosat-0.6.3        | 108 KB    | ########## | 100% 
psutil-5.8.0         | 342 KB    | ########## | 100% 
sqlite-3.35.4        | 1.4 MB    | ########## | 100% 
zstd-1.4.9           | 809 KB    | ########## | 100% 
jinja2-3.0.0         | 99 KB     | ########## | 100% 
brotlipy-0.7.0       | 349 KB    | ########## | 100% 
ripgrep-12.1.1       | 1.5 MB    | ########## | 100% 
_libgcc_mutex-0.1    | 3 KB      | ########## | 100% 
six-1.15.0           | 13 KB     | ########## | 100% 
soupsieve-2.2.1      | 30 KB     | ########## | 100% 
pyopenssl-20.0.1     | 48 KB     | ########## | 100% 

Downloading and Extracting Packages

UnicodeDecodeError('ascii', '/info/test/tests/data/\xed\x94\x84\xeb\xa1\x9c\xea\xb7\xb8\xeb\x9e\xa8.zip.json', 22, 23, 'ordinal not in range(128)')


The command '/bin/sh -c conda install conda-build' returned a non-zero code: 1
```

Comment: If the point is to Dockerize cadquery, why not use an existing image? https://github.com/RubenRubens/cq-containers#available-containers

Comment: Yes that is the point. I have succesfully used that image. But i have also used other apps  - relevant to each other that used docker but had `FROM ubuntu`. Now i want to chain everything together and have one docker image. The dockerfile to dockerize cad query uses FROM `continuumio/miniconda3`. Which then uses `FROM debian`. So what i did is i modified the continuumio/miniconda3 image, to use `FROM ubuntu`. The first part of the process (modifiying continuumio/miniconda3) works. It's the second part - downloading cadquery, that fails.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Conda is Too Old

I replicated this error with the `continuumio/miniconda2:4.5.11` Docker image:

```bash
$ docker run --rm -it continuumio/miniconda2:4.5.11 bash
(base) root@a285050719ad:/# conda install -y conda-build

# ... similar output as OP ...

UnicodeDecodeError('ascii', '/info/test/tests/data/\xed\x94\x84\xeb\xa1\x9c\xea\xb7\xb8\xeb\x9e\xa8.zip.json', 22, 23, 'ordinal not in range(128)')
```

Additionally, attempting to upgrade the `conda` package fails with some extra advice:

```bash
(base) root@a285050719ad:/# conda update conda
Solving environment: done

EncodingError: A unicode encoding or decoding error has occurred.
Python 2 is the interpreter under which conda is running in your base environment.
Replacing your base environment with one having Python 3 may help resolve this issue.
If you still have a need for Python 2 environments, consider using 'conda create'
and 'conda activate'.  For example:

    $ conda create -n py2 python=2
    $ conda activate py2

Error details: UnicodeDecodeError('ascii', '/info/test/tests/data/\xed\x94\x84\xeb\xa1\x9c\xea\xb7\xb8\xeb\x9e\xa8.zip.json', 22, 23, 'ordinal not in range(128)')
```

That is, you really shouldn't be using these old Miniconda2 images because the `conda` is no longer compatible with the Anaconda Cloud repository.

### Use Newer Miniconda Installer

A clean solution is to install a newer Miniconda (or Miniforge or Mambaforge). The latest ones all have Python 3 in the **base**. If for some reason one must have Python 2 in the **base**, which means you can't have the latest `conda` nor the latest `conda-build`, then it seems [Miniconda up to 4.8.3 supported Python 2](https://repo.anaconda.com/miniconda/).

If possible, *use the latest version*, as in Python 3. One can always create a Python 2 environment if needed - just better that it not be in the **base**. Suggested solution:

```bash
RUN wget --quiet https://repo.anaconda.com/miniconda/Miniconda3-latest-Linux-x86_64.sh -O ~/miniconda.sh && \
...
```

Also, consider whether you can more simply start from an existing Docker image with Conda preinstalled.

### Update Conda in Place (Not Recommended)

A dirty version would be still using the same 4.5.11 installer, but then upgrading immediately. In the Docker image I can get it to upgrade to 4.8 and keep Python 2.7, then `conda-build` will install at 3.18.11 (current as of May 2021 is 3.21.4).

This could similarly be done in the Dockerfile with something like

```bash
RUN conda install -y python=2.7 conda=4.8 && \
    conda clean -qafy && \
    conda install -y conda-build && \
    conda clean -qafy
```

Note: I needed the first clean to get `conda-build` to install.

Comment: Thanks a ton!!! You mentioned `continuumio/miniconda2:4.5.11`. It's funny because the first part of my dockerfile is a modified `continuumio/miniconda3` image. I just used ubuntu instead of debian and added some stuff for the time zone. So the first part of the image passes. The seconda part (i updated the dockerfile with comment - to see where the second part begins) is the dockerfile which is used to download cadquery, which used `FROM continuumio/miniconda3`. I just chained the two dockerfiles together. But since cadquery works, i dont know why my conjoined version does not.

Comment: I am a little confused by your answer. What is the problematic line in my dockerfile? Is this issue fixable?

Comment: Aha, so i was using miniconda2. So i should replace this line `RUN wget --quiet https://repo.anaconda.com/miniconda/Miniconda2-4.5.11-Linux-x86_64.sh -O ~/miniconda.sh && \
    /bin/bash ~/miniconda.sh -b -p /opt/conda && \
    rm ~/miniconda.sh && \
    ln -s /opt/conda/etc/profile.d/conda.sh /etc/profile.d/conda.sh && \
    echo ". /opt/conda/etc/profile.d/conda.sh" >> ~/.bashrc && \
    echo "conda activate base" >> ~/.bashrc` with the one you mention? Is this correct?

Comment: @user1584421 Don't replace that whole thing - only change `Miniconda2-4.5.11-Linux-x86_64.sh` to `Miniconda3-latest-Linux-x86_64.sh`.